# How to stub wsdl service endpoints?

Tags: java, web-services, soap, wsdl

I want to run some integration tests on a `WSDL` client application. Therefore I'd like to have the WSDL server (which is not in control of me) to response with the same xml response always.

How could I achieve this? Is there any tool out that offers a wsdl endpoint an can always return the same xml (which I then could take from my live logs)?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

[SOAPUI](http://www.soapui.org/soap-mocking/working-with-mockservices.html) offers this functionality. I've used it before with ease.

Alternatively if you do not want to go through the hassle of converting the WSDL request to a meaningful response, take a look at services like [mocky](http://www.mocky.io/) which simply echo back a payload.

Answer (score 1):

Take a look at [Soap-UI](http://www.soapui.org/) - it has the ability to mock web services exactly as you mentioned using just a wsdl. You can then decide which XML the mocked web service will return, and it will run as a server locally. Instead of pointing to the 'real' server you can then point to your own local endpoint in order to retreive the same response. More information available on my blog [here](http://philsjavaworld.blogspot.co.uk/2014/04/mocking-web-services-when-third-parties.html)